# Installing certificate under a different user causes Access Denied while not logged in to VM

Tags: windows, powershell, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine

I'm building a VM image in Azure through automation pipelines using PowerShell. One of the requirements is to install a certificate on the CurrentUser store for a specific user. When I am **currently logged into the VM**, I can run the following command through [Azure Run Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command):

```powershell
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord

$session = New-PSSession $env:ComputerName -credential $Credential

$command = {
    param($certPassword, $filePath)
    Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $filePath -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password $certPassword 
}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $command -ArgumentList $certPassword,$filePath -Session $session
```

When I am not currently logged into the VM under that user, I get an `Access Denied` error. The error goes away as soon as I login to the machine again. If I run the pipeline while I'm logged into the VM, it succeeds.

What is different about PowerShell permissions while I am logged into the VM?

Comment: Wait, so it works when you manually run it while logged in; i.e.: `Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $filePath -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password $certPassword`, but when running it remotely (*using `Invoke-Command`*) it doesn't?

Comment: `New-PSSession` **does** simulate a user login. Which specific command is returning the `Access Denied`, `New-PSSession`? To start a PS Session, even locally, the user **must** be a member of the local group `Administrators` or `Remote Management Users`.

Comment: A different option is to use saps like: `Start-Process powershell.exe -Wait -Credential $cred -ArgumentList ('-c',"Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $filePath -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password $certPassword")` just be aware that any errors from the command will not get output to az

Comment: Thanks for the responses all! To answer some of the questions, I tested again. I need to update my question-- it only works *while* I am logged into the machine. The access denied error is actually from the `Import-PfxCertificate` command, not the session creation or `Invoke-Command`.